# `gets`not working when used in `if...end`statement

Tags: ruby

I want to find a way for my script to wait until the user hits ENTER, while using a `if...end`

```
input = 3

if input > 2    
    puts "input is greater than 2"
    gets
    puts "this shouldn't appear before I type ENTER"
end
```

This does not work as I get

```
$input is greater than 2
$this shouldn't appear before I type ENTER
```

what should I use instead of `gets` to pause the script ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: are you reading from console? Or from a file?

Comment: the code is pausing fine for me. Is there more code around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace `gets` with `$stdin.gets`

Comment: Why is this needed?

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me, are your sure you want to read from console?

```
input = 3

if input > 2    
    puts "input is greater than 2"
    puts "please enter your name"
    name = gets
    puts "hi #{name} this shouldn't appear before I type ENTER"
end
```

o/p

```
~/Desktop$ ruby demo.rb
input is greater than 2
please enter your name
salil
hi salil
 this shouldn't appear before I type ENTER
```